# Sharing url on google plus via url with microdata

Tags: fragment, google-plus, microdata

My problem is that using the following code I can not share on google plus using microdata but uses OpenGraph data located at the top of the website. Why?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <div class="quote-txt">
    <span itemprop="name">Frases Celebres</span>
    <span itemprop="description">El principio más profundo del carácter humano es el anhelo de ser apreciado</span>
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://www.frasecelebre.net//resources/images/social_logo.png">                    

  </div>
  <div class="qfooter col-xs-12">
    <div class="qsocial">
      <a class="googleplus social-icon" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.frasecelebre.ocioportales.com%2Ftemas%2Fsentimientos%2Fbesos.html" title="Compartir frase en Google plus" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>                    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are sharing to Google+ is the list page and Google+ take the metadate from that page. If you want each article to have unique metadate it needs it's own unique URL as well.

Comment: Wow ... that's just what I wanted to avoid. Trying to avoid creating a unique url for each user who famously shared. Thanks and best regards!